# Mistake - should have used ericaceous compost

Tags: compost, ph

I repotted a camellia yesterday but used multi purpose compost by mistake.

That compost is on the bottom, but I used rotted manure around the root ball.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you only did it yesterday, it's not a problem - what could be a major problem is surrounding the rootball with manure. Go and get some ericaceous compost if you don't have any. Turn the Camellia out, remove the manure, empty the pot completely. If you really must use manure in a pot, make sure it's well rotted and smells just earthy (personally, I don't recommend the use of rotted manure in pots, unless you know 100% how it's been produced/composted) then either mix a small amount in with your ericaceous compost, or put a layer on the bottom of the pot, fill with ericaceous  compost, then repot the Camellia into that.

Were it my Camellia, I'd just stick with ericaceous compost and provide a separate fertiliser for use with acid loving plants in subsequent years in spring.

Comment: Thanks. The manure is well rotted though, earthy smelling.

Comment: Even so, it shouldn't be entirely round the rootball - I don't  like manure in pots because its a possible source of pathogens and weed seeds at the very least.

Comment: I totally agree with Bamboo except I would be more adamant that you just use sterilized potting soil with no added fertilizer no silly moisture holding gimmicks like 'sponges' or  'gels'.  The entire pot should be soil no rock at the bottom either.  There are potting soils made for acid loving plants that are very common.  There is also fertilizer sold for acid loving plants that helps to add acidity to the soil.  That is enough.  And the higher nitrogen will cause your Camellia to not flower!  Lots of leaves, though.  And re pot and get rid of the manure altogether.

Comment: Thanks. I have pulled out the root ball and repotted it using just ericaceous compost. Hopefully it will be fine.